# How to check if file exists in remote SFTP server from local Linux script?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, sftp

I'm writing a `sh` script to download a file from a Windows SFTP server. However, before doing so I want to check if the file exists.

There were many questions out there that suggests downloading winexe, or doing `ssh host@host test -f file` and other alternatives, but all of them would not work in my case. I'm not allowed to install anything and must use out-of-the-box utils.

The reason why I need to test before the actual download is because there is a lot of pre-existing processes already set up that requires the file to exist before reaching the download portion. Don't ask me why it is this way. It was already like this when I came in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard (OpenSSH) SFTP client does not offer a function to test a file existence or anything close to it.

---

I'm assuming your only interface is the SFTP protocol to make the solution platform-independent (as you are connecting to Windows). So solutions like executing `test` over an SSH terminal are not viable (as you have confirmed yourself).

---

You can workaround that by using an SFTP command with a little overhead that fails when the file does not exist. And test for the `sftp` exit code (1 for error, 0 for ok).

You could abuse the `df` (disk free) command for that.

```sh
echo "df myfile.txt" | sftp -b - example.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Though `df` command uses a proprietary OpenSSH extension of the SFTP protocol internally (`statvfs@openssh.com`). So you have to test first, if your Windows SFTP server supports that. Obviously if you use OpenSSH (MS Win32 build or Cygwin), you are ok.

---

If the `df` won't work, the only other option is to try to download the file.

Ideally move your download code before all *"pre-existing processes already set up that requires the file to exist"*. That's imo the best solution. As @Kenster commented: *The file could disappear between when you check and when you download it. Or the file could exist, but you could lack permission to read it. Checking whether the file exists, separately from trying to download it, may not be as useful as you think.*

If that's not possible, you need to download the file twice. First to test its existence. And later again to actually download it.

Fake download to test file existence:

```sh
echo "get myfile.txt /dev/null" | sftp -b - example.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Replace the `/dev/null` with an actual path, if you can merge the test and download steps into one.

---

The SFTP protocol as such can test file existence. So if you have other SFTP client than OpenSSH handy, you might be able to do this more easily.

For example the [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/) has the [`find`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) command:

```sh
lftp -c "open sftp://example.com ; find myfile.txt"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

---

For a similar question, see [Test if any file was downloaded with SFTP command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/520993/119732).